# The results of find() mongoDB are different

Tags: django, pymongo

I used pymongo 2.6.3 with django 1.5.4

The result of search page is sometimes different after refresh.

```
db.test.find({'temp':{'$regex':'The'}})
```

Of course, when I have one more refreshed, the result is same.

For example, the try(refresh) number

> 1, 3 : same
>
> 2 : different

Do you have any experience about it?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser/server might be caching results. If you don't want to hit the cache try having your request string as something like:

```
http://yourserver?_=random()
```